# Replace text between two marker with a file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, replace

I would like to replace a text `INSERT` in `template.js` with file content from `insert.json` and write it to a `result.js`.

insert.json:

```json
{
  "insert": true,
  "other": "you can ignore line indentation"
}
```

template.js:

```js
function test() {
  const x = INSERT;
  console.log(x);
}
```

result.js:

```js
function test() {
  const x = {
  "insert": true,
  "other": "you can ignore line indentation"
};
  console.log(x);
}
```

I am searching to replace `INSERT`. But a alternative for example regular expression to find, is also great:

- `const x = (INSERT);` to replace `$INSERT`
- `(const x = )INSERT(;)` to replace `$1 $INSERT $2`

You can't use something like `$(cat insert.json)`, because the insert.json file is huge and exeed terminal character limit.

**Edit:**
I didn't express myself correctly. The file isn't really that big. So there is no memory problem in RAM or on the hard drive.

The file is around 200 kb. That's tiny, see:

- `du -h insert.json`: 196 kb
- `wc -l insertjson`: 6416 lines
- `wc -m insert.json`: 198740 characters

If I do this with sed...

```bash
LANG=C sed "s/INSERT/const x = $(cat insert.json)/g" template.js > result.js
```

...there are 2 problems:

- sed: The argument list is too long (Too much data in a terminal command)
- sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unterminated `s' command (bad character, because insert.json has special character)

Comment: You should be able to do this with `sed`.

Comment: Terminal limits are irrelevant. `$(cat insert.json)` uses as many bytes of memory as the size of `insert.json`. Exactly how large is your largest `insert.json`? Are you sure that there isn't that much memory available.

Comment: @pts Can run into issues if the contents of the file are being passed as a command line argument. I believe there's a limit on total size, not just number of arguments.

Comment: @Shawn: Indeed, there are limits on the total byte size of command-line arguments. However, they are not terminal limits, they apply even if a terminal is not used. Thus my comment stating that *terminal limits are irrelevant* is still true.

Comment: @pts I edited the post above about the memory limit. It's not a RAM problem, but rather the command-line arguments are too long or there are special characters in the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to solve it straightforwardly with `"$(cat insert.json)"`, without triggering the command-line arguments too long error, because the limit applies only to external commands run by the shell. Shel built-in commands are only limited by available memory.

This works in Bash, Zsh, Ksh, BusyBox sh, but not in Dash (because Dash doesn't support the `//` substitution), all without any external commands other than `cat`:

```bash
INSERT="$(cat insert.json)"
TEMPLATE="$(cat template.js)"
printf '%s\n' "${TEMPLATE//INSERT/$INSERT}" >result.js
```

In Bash, Zsh and Ksh (but not in BusyBox sh) both instances of `cat` above can be replaced with `<`, and then it won't use any external commands at all.

Variable assignment (`=`) and the command `printf` are built in to the shells above, thus they work with strings longer than the command-line argument limit.

Comment: I would say that is the solution. It's super simple and bash-friendly.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    old = "INSERT"
}
NR == FNR {
    new = (NR>1 ? new ORS : "") $0
    next
}
s = index($0,old) {
    $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old))
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk insert.json template.js
function test() {
  const x = {
  "insert": true,
  "other": "you can ignore line indentation"
};
  console.log(x);
}
```

but if it were me I'd want to have sensible indenting in the output, e.g. using any POSIX awk, this will indent the new string with whatever indenting the line containing the old string starts with:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    old = "INSERT"
}
NR == FNR {
    new = (NR>1 ? new ORS : "") $0
    next
}
s = index($0,old) {
    rep = new
    gsub(ORS,ORS substr($0,1,match($0,/[^[:space:]]/)-1),rep)
    $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) rep substr($0,s+length(old))
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk insert.json template.js
function test() {
  const x = {
    "insert": true,
    "other": "you can ignore line indentation"
  };
  console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: Pretty. I tried this with awk but didn't succeed. Your script works.

Answer (score 1):

Typically such substitutions are solved with `sed`, `awk` or `perl`. However, extra care has to be taken to avoid reading *insert.json* to memory. See my other answer for a simpler solution if there is enough memory for *insert.json*.

All solutions below avoid reading *insert.json* to memory, so they work well even if it's huge. They also work in many shells (e.g. Bash, Dash, Zsh, BusyBox sh etc.).

This works without any external commands besides `cat`:

```bash
( TEMPLATE="$(cat template.js)"
  while true; do
    TEMPLATE2="${TEMPLATE#*INSERT}"
    test "$TEMPLATE" = "$TEMPLATE2" && break
    printf '%s' "${TEMPLATE%%INSERT*}"
    cat insert.json
    TEMPLATE="$TEMPLATE2"
  done
  printf '%s\n' "$TEMPLATE"
) >result.js
```

This works without any external commands, but it strips leading whitespace from each line, and is much slower for large files:

```bash
( TEMPLATE="$(while read -r L; do printf '%s\n' "$L"; done <template.js)"
  while true; do
    TEMPLATE2="${TEMPLATE#*INSERT}"
    test "$TEMPLATE" = "$TEMPLATE2" && break
    printf '%s' "${TEMPLATE%%INSERT*}"
    while read -r L; do printf '%s\n' "$L"; done <insert.json
    TEMPLATE="$TEMPLATE2"
  done
  printf '%s\n' "$TEMPLATE"
) >result.js
```

Common pitfalls the solutions above avoid:

- Using constructs which work in Bash only, e.g. `TEMPLATE="$(<template.js)"`
- Omitting the `-r` flag from `read`. Without the `-r` flag, `read` processes backslashes in the input lone.
- Using `echo` instead of `printf`. `echo` in Dash processes backslashes.
- Using an implicit cat, e.g. `TEMPLATE="$(<template.js)"` runs `cat`.

Comment: Keep in mind for the second solution that `while read` is quite slow - if your `insert.json` is so big that you can't afford to read it into memory then you will probably also notice a pretty big speed penalty trying to iterate over it in bash.

Comment: @tjm3772: Thank you, I've added speed info to my answer. I don't think there is anything faster though without running external commands.

Comment: I edited the post above about the memory limit. It's not a RAM problem, but rather the command-line arguments are too long or there are special characters in the command.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the requirements. The solutions in this answer still work unchanged.

Comment: In any case, I learned something new here that I can perhaps implement in other projects.
I'm not sure if the while loop is really necessary because it would have to abort the first time.
This should be a better option, similar to another variant in the thread, postet from you too:

REPLACE='INSERT';
TEMPLATE="$(cat template.js)";
(
    printf '%s' "${TEMPLATE%%${REPLACE}*}";
    cat insert.json;
    printf '%s\n' "${TEMPLATE#*${REPLACE}}";
) > result.js

Comment: I've added the while loop so that it works no matter how many instances of `INSERT` are present. It's more useful and future-proof than a solution which assumes that there is always 1 `INSERT`, and silently prints incorrect ouput otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using Python, the solution is simple:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# main.py
with open("insert.json") as stream:
    text = stream.read().strip()
with open("template.js") as stream:
    content = stream.read()
with open("result.js", "w") as stream:
    stream.write(content.replace("INSERT", text))
```

To run this script:

```bash
python3 main.py
```

The first two `with` blocks reads information and the last one writes them out. Compare to using bash, sed, awk, ... Python solution is easier to read and understand.

Comment: Python 3 converts input bytes to Unicode and back (without `open(..., "rb")`). If the input file contains invalid UTF-8, the solution above fails with a UnicodeDecodeError.

Comment: I'm not necessarily a fan of Python, but this is nice.

Answer (score 0):

Going off the beaten path a bit, a [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/) script:

```lisp
#!/usr/bin/env racket
#lang racket/base
(require racket/cmdline racket/file racket/match)

(define (replace-text what insert-file template-file)
  (define with (file->bytes insert-file))
  (define end-of-with ; Don't output a trailing newline from the replacement
    (match (regexp-match-positions #rx#"\r?\n$" with)
      [`((,start-of-newline . ,_)) start-of-newline]
      [#f (bytes-length with)]))
  (call-with-input-file template-file
    (lambda (template-port)
      (define (next-match) (regexp-match what template-port 0 #f (current-output-port)))
      (do ([found (next-match) (next-match)])
        ((not found))
        (write-bytes with (current-output-port) 0 end-of-with)))))

(command-line #:args (replace-string insert-file template-file)
              (replace-text (regexp (regexp-quote replace-string))
                            insert-file
                            template-file))
```

Example:

```bash
$ ./inserter INSERT insert.js template.js
function test() {
  const x = {
  "insert": true,
  "other": "you can ignore line indentation"
};
  console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: This is not very portable, because most Linux and Unix systems don't have *racket* installed out of the box.

Comment: This solution seems to read the file *insert.js* to memory, and the question seems to indicate that *insert.js* is too large for that.

Comment: Eh, it's available in pretty much every distribution's package manager. I'm not super concerned about portability with this answer anyways.

Comment: (If it's possible to guarantee the file doesn't have a trailing newline, or its presence is okay to have, there's a simpler alternative that doesn't involve reading the whole file. But, again, not concerned about that because I'm not worried about the "command line too long" issue I mentioned in a comment on the top level question. And OP clarified about the length of the file.)

Comment: You can do something similar in perl, python, etc., but Racket's `regexp-match` function has the interesting ability to match directly from an input port/stream, not just a string, *and* print unmatched text to an output port/stream. Makes it very useful for a task like this.

Comment: I edited the post above about the memory limit. It's not a RAM problem, but rather the command-line arguments are too long or there are special characters in the command.

Comment: Also off the beaten path, a shell pipeline to use if you have `sam` from Plan 9 available: `printf "%s\n" "/INSERT/r insert.js" "w result.js" | sam -d template.js 2>/dev/null` (It has the aforementioned issue, if it's an issue, with a trailing newline in insert.js, though)

Comment: I'm really sorry to say this, but when I first looked at the code and racket in general, I thought it must be an esoteric programming language. xD
I haven't tested this solution. To be honest, in such a case I would actually rather develop it in C++ or go-lang.
Nevertheless, thanks for the contribution. Maybe someone else can use it.